# Having split HTML divs by heading type, how to extract the one I'm interested in?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

Given a page such as [this](http://jobs.kelkoo.co.uk/), with two jobs (we'll ignore 'Open applications' for now) fully described one after the other, I can detect if there is a job matching a keyword by applying the following XPath:

```
//*[self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4][contains(., 'Country Manager')]
```

via Python:

```
import urllib2
import lxml.html as lh    
url = 'http://jobs.kelkoo.co.uk/'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()
root = lh.fromstring(content)
job_titles = root.xpath("//*[self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4][contains(., 'Country Manager')]")
```

I can then determine which type of is involved thus:

```
tags = [e.tag for e in titles]
```

Knowing that we are dealing with a `<h2>`, I am looking to extract the individual job spec. I know I can delineate each `<h2>` using the following:

```
//div[count(preceding-sibling::h2)=1]
```

But how to I connect the knowledge of where the job title in question is found, with its tag type, and with the above delineation?

I've tried to put the keyword back into the above delineating XPath, but I'm told it's not a valid expression:

```
//div[count(preceding-sibling::h2[contains(text(), 'Country Manager')]=1]
```

Comment: It seems I can do the following, but will it always be reliable? `for i in e.itersiblings():
    print i.text_content()`

Answer (score 1):

Find the [following `div` sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) with `class="jobspecs"`:

```
for title in job_titles:
    print(title.text_content())

    for spec in title.xpath("following-sibling::div[@class='jobspecs']/ul/li/span[@class='label']"):
        spec_name = spec.text_content().strip()
        spec_value = spec.xpath("following-sibling::text()")[0].strip()

        print(spec_name, spec_value)

    print("----")
```

Prints:

```
Country Manager - Uk
Contract type: Permanent
Hours per week: 40
Site: London
----
```

Answer (score 1):

Each job on [your example page](http://jobs.kelkoo.co.uk/) is within a `<div class="jobitem">`

```
            <div class="jobitem">
        <h2>Country Manager - Uk</h2>
        <div class="jobspecs">
            <ul>
                <li><span class="label">Contract type: </span>Permanent</li>
                <li><span class="label">Hours per week: </span>40</li>
                <li></li>
                <li><span class="label">Site: </span>London</li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="jobdesc">
            <p>Role overview:</p>
            ...
```

So you can:

- select the "jobitem" elements by looking at heading and their text content,

getting job elements:

```
import urllib2
import lxml.html as lh    
url = 'http://jobs.kelkoo.co.uk/'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()
root = lh.fromstring(content)
jobs = root.xpath('''
    //div[@class='jobitem']
         [child::*[self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4]
                  [contains(., $query)]]''',
    query="Country Manager")
```

(this above uses XPath variables that lxml supports, but you could use `[contains(., "Country Manager")]`)

- looping over them,
- and inside the loop, relatively selecting children `<div>` elements you want (XPath expressions starting with `./` to be safe), using @alecxe 's suggested `[@class="jobspecs"]` for example.

Something like this:

```
>>> for job in jobs:
...     title = job.xpath('normalize-space(h2|h3|h4)')
...     specs = job.xpath('string(./div[@class="jobspecs"])').strip()
...     desc = job.xpath('string(./div[@class="jobdesc"])').strip()
...     print('-------')
...     print(title)
...     print('-------')
...     print(specs)
...     print('-------')
...     print(desc)
...     
... 
-------
Country Manager - Uk
-------
Contract type: Permanent
                    Hours per week: 40

                    Site: London
-------
Role overview:
Reporting in to the European Commercial Director, the UK/IE Country Manager is a senior manager with full responsibility for the sales, traffic and product functions across two countries. He/She will drive the UK sales and traffic functions and manage a team of highly skilled digital account managers based in London.
The role involves sales planning, account growth planning, forecasting, data analysis and high level presentations with senior internal and external parties. The CM is responsible for the Gross Margin position and goals of the country, managing yield prices, cost of sale prices and the overall financial management of conversion over a large number of merchants and traffic partners.
The critical equations of broking between revenue, cost of leads and understanding the merchant perspective on volume, performance and quality is key to this role. This person will need little day to day management and will be a natural leader who is respected for their knowledge, commitment and ability.
Accountabilities and Deliverables:
-Develop strong relationships with key UK merchants and agencies that drive growth and take best advantage of all opportunities
- Work closely with EU counterparts to identify and maximise pan-euro opportunities where required, drive these deals through to completion either on own initiative or as part of the wider European team
- Use initiative to identity and push new opportunities; from growth of existing channels to creation of new ones
- Full control and management of the UK/IE commercial teams; able to delegate tasks and responsibilities while respecting their staffs experience and ability;
Previous Experience/Skills required:
- 6+ years experience in a proven sales/marketing management role, in digital/e-commerce.
- Understanding of the price comparison market.
- Understanding of digital marketing and online advertising.
- Contacts in online retail
Person Specification/Competencies:
- Good negotiation skills and ability to close deals quickly.
- Very strong communication and presentation skills to get best results in both local country and where required across Europe (proven track record in creating and maintaining a productive network)
- Excellent internal and external customer relationship and interpersonal skills.
- Team player with strong work ethic and ability to adapt to and drive change.
- Commercially minded.
- Strategic thinker and able to think analytically at a detailed level.
- Proven leadership skills.
- Ability to strongly influence those outside direct control for positive results.
- Displays respect to all colleagues and encourages this behaviour in own team.
- Able to deliver at a consistently high level in a demanding commercial environment.
- Manages conflict in a positive and assertive manner for best outcome
Academic Background:
- Strong academic background; preferably a minimum 2:1 degree or equivalen
Requirements/Other Information:
- Role holder must be able to travel freely across Europe and be eligible to work in the UK
Good reasons to join us
- Company highly recognized in its market
- Help our customer drive core of their business
- Opportunity to show your full potential in a growing business
- Chance to work with incredibly smart, talented, and interesting folks                

                        Apply


                        Download details
```

Comment: There are many such sites so I won't know the class name of the div in question in advance. Great answer though, thanks.